# Can't scrape all the links and their sublinks from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fetch all the links recursively that are located under `Automotive` in the left-sided area of this [webpage](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0).

It is necessary to use all the collected links recursively as each link has branches.

For example if you click on any of the links under [Automotive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n59aj.jpg), you will most probably see that there are couple of links connected to each link and so on.

My current implementation can only fetch the links from the landing page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'

def fetch_all_links(link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
    if not soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):return
    for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
        yield item.get("href")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
        for elem in fetch_all_links(link):
            print(elem)
```

Question: How can I grab all the links and their sub-links from the left-sided area of the aforementioned webpage?

Answer (score 2):

The following code yields a lot of results, all of which cannot be printed due to `StackOverflow` limitations. There are a lot of duplicated links (the same item is listed under different categories). The second version will not print the duplicates; you decide which one you prefer. You can also decide what values to `yield` based on what your needs are. **This code also use a threadpool to concurrently read all links for a given level**:

**Version 1 with Duplicate Links**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def get_page(session, url):
    resp = session.get(url)
    return resp.text


def get_links(session, executor, page, level):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    selector = 'li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]'
    links = soup.select(selector)
    if not links:
        return
    urls = [link.get('href') for link in links]
    titles = [link.text for link in links]
    pages = list(executor.map(partial(get_page, session), urls))
    for i in range(len(links)):
        yield level, titles[i], urls[i]
        yield from get_links(session, executor, pages[i], level + 1)

with requests.Session() as session:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        resp = session.get('https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0')
        page = resp.text
        for level, title, href in get_links(session, executor, page, 0):
            spacing = ' ' * (level * 4)
            print(f'{spacing}{title}: {href}')
```

**Version 2 Without Duplicate Links**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def get_page(session, url):
    resp = session.get(url)
    return resp.text

seen_links = set()

def get_links(session, executor, page, level):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    selector = 'li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]'
    links = soup.select(selector)
    if not links:
        return
    new_links = []
    # don't process links we have seen:
    for link in links:
        url =  link.get('href')
        if url not in seen_links:
            new_links.append(link)
            seen_links.add(url)
    urls = [link.get('href') for link in new_links]
    titles = [link.text for link in new_links]
    pages = list(executor.map(partial(get_page, session), urls))
    for i in range(len(new_links)):
        yield level, titles[i], urls[i]
        yield from get_links(session, executor, pages[i], level + 1)

with requests.Session() as session:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        resp = session.get('https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0')
        page = resp.text
        for level, title, href in get_links(session, executor, page, 0):
            spacing = ' ' * (level * 4)
            print(f'{spacing}{title}: {href}')
```

Prints (in part due to StackOverflow limitations):

```
Car Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79919031
    Alternators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504415031
    Batteries & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82523031
        Battery Charging Units: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82526031
        Battery Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933113031
        Battery Testers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82527031
        Car Batteries: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82524031
        Jump Leads: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82525031
    Belts & Tensioners: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504430031
        Idler Pulleys: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/8490903031
        Serpentine Belts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/14343385031
        Tensioner Levers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933115031
        Tensioner Pulleys: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933116031
        Timing Belt Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/8490902031
        Timing Belts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504432031
        V-Drive Belts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504431031
    Brakes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79984031
        ABS & EBS Components & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/80010031
        Brake Shoes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79987031
        Brake Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933120031
        Brake Pads: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504242031
        Braking Force Regulator: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933121031
        Power Brake Systems: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79999031
        Brake Pipes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79989031
        Brake Disc Rotors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504243031
        Brake Hoses, Lines & Fittings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79991031
            Fittings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933119031
            Hoses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933117031
            Lines: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933118031
        Sensors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504462031
        Callipers & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79990031
            Brake Calliper Tool Sets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2502065031
            Calliper Bolts & Guide Pins: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933122031
            Calliper Brackets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933123031
            Calliper Covers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/14439426031
            Calliper Pistons: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933124031
            Callipers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933125031
        Brake Drums: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79992031
        Pneumatic Systems & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79994031
        Handbrake Components: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933131031
            Handbrake Lever Return Springs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933133031
            Handbrake Levers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933134031
            Handbrake Shoes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933135031
            Handbrake Systems: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933136031
            Parking Cables: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933132031
        Master Cylinders: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933130031
        Master Cylinder Repair Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933129031
        Wheel Cylinders: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933142031
        Wheel Cylinder Repair Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933141031
    Car Styling & Body Fittings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/80019031
    Drive & Transmission: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2503993031
        Automatic Gearboxes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951722031
        Bearings & Bearing Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/300703031
        Clutches & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81484031
        Drive Shafts & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81494031
        Manual Gearboxes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951723031
        Seals: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504006031
    Engine & Engine Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81446031
        Chip Tuning: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/667732031
        Cooling & Heating Systems: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951724031
        Engine Blocks: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81449031
        Engine Compartments: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81447031
        Engine Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951752031
            Camshafts & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951753031
            Connecting Rods & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951759031
                Bearings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951760031
                Connecting Rods: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951762031
                Nuts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951763031
            Crankcase Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951764031
                Gasket Sets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951765031
                Ventilation Hoses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951766031
                Ventilation Valves: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951767031
            Crankshafts & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951768031
                Bearings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951769031
                Gears: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951772031
                Pulleys: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951773031
                Seals: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951774031
            Cylinder Head Gaskets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951775031
            Cylinder Heads: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81450031
            Engine Gasket Sets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951776031
            Engine Mounts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951777031
            Main Bearings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951778031
            Main Bolts & Studs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951779031
            Oil Pans: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2502036031
            Oil Pumps: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951780031
            Pistons & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951781031
                Pistons: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951784031
                Rings & Ring Sets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951786031
            Rocker Arms: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951787031
            Sensors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951788031
                Air Mass: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504467031
                Barometric Pressure: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504463031
                Camshaft Position: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504468031
                Crankshaft Position: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504466031
                Detonation: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504464031
                MAP Sensors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951791031
                Oil Level: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951792031
                Throttle Position: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504469031
            Timing Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951795031
            Turbochargers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504420031
            Valves & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951796031
                Guides: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951799031
                Seals: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951801031
                Shims: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951803031
                Springs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951804031
                Valves: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951805031
        Petrol Supply & Treatments: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81457031
    Exhaust & Exhaust Systems: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81460031
        Catalytic Converter Kits & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951833031
        Catalytic Converter Mounting Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951834031
        Catalytic Converters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81466031
        Clamps, Flanges & Hangers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951835031
        Complete Installations: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81467031
        End Pipes & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952563031
        Exhaust Gas Recirculation Cleaners & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81481031
            Cleaners: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952564031
            Valve Coolers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952565031
            Valve Gaskets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952566031
            Valves: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504131031
        Exhaust Manifolds & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952572031
        Exhaust Systems: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81472031
        Extension Pipes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952568031
        Headers & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952569031
            Bolts, Studs & Nuts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952570031
            Headers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81474031
        Intake Manifolds: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81468031
        Oxygen Sensors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81469031
        Pipes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81471031
        Seals: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81463031
        Silencer Mounting Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4952576031
        Silencers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81475031
    Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504306031
        Air Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81453031
            Cabin Air Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958533031
            Engine Air Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958534031
        Coolant Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958535031
        Fuel Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958536031
        Oil Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504307031
        Service Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958537031
        Transmission Filters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958538031
    Fuses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82508031
        Flat Fuses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82509031
        Glass Fuses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82510031
        Mini Fuses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82511031
    Ignition & Tools: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81322031
        Glow Plugs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504483031
        Ignition & Heating System: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81323031
        Ignition Cable: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81324031
        Spark Plug Connectors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2502073031
        Spark Plug Wrenches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2846389031
        Spark Plugs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504494031
    Instruments: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81436031
        Clocks: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81444031
        Fuel Gauges: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81441031
        Instrument Panels: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81439031
        Nuts & Bolts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81440031
        Oil Temperature Indicators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81442031
        Rev Counters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81437031
        Speedometers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81438031
        Water Temperature Indicators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81445031
    Interior Fittings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81361031
    Lights, Bulbs & Indicators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81326031
        HID Conversion Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958714031
        Light Bulbs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81345031
            Exterior Light Bulbs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958715031
            Interior Light Bulbs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958716031
            Special Bulbs: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81351031
            Universal Bulb Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958720031
        Lighting Assemblies & Components: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958721031
            Angel Eyes: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81327031
            Daytime Running Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81331031
            Fog Light Assemblies: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81338031
            Headlight Assemblies: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81336031
            Headlight Components & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958722031
                Bezels: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958723031
                Brackets: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958724031
                Bulb Holders: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958725031
                Covers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958726031
                Eyebrows: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958727031
                Housings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958728031
                Lenses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958729031
            Interior Lighting: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81332031
            Neon Spots & Bars: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81342031
            Number Plate Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504238031
            Parking Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81333031
            Rear Light Assemblies: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81330031
            Rear Light Components & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958732031
                Lenses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4958735031
            Side Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81343031
            Third Brake Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81335031
            Turn Signal Lights: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81328031
            Underbody Light Stripes & Kits: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81334031
    Sensors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81502031
        Fuel Injection: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951829031
        Coolant Temperature: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504465031
            Engine Cooling & Heating: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81452031
            Compressors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951737031
            Engine Fans: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951739031
            Expansion Valves: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951740031
            Fittings: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951741031
            Heater Cores: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951742031
            Intercoolers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951743031
            Oil Pressure Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964580031
            Radiators & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951745031
                Radiator Caps: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/11416518031
                Radiator Fan Clutches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951746031
                Radiator Fans: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951747031
                Radiator Hoses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951748031
                Radiator Supports: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/14301191031
                Radiators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951749031
            Temperature Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964585031
            Thermostats: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951750031
            Water Pumps: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951751031
        Ambient Air Temperature: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504471031
            AC & Interior Heating: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951725031
            Accumulators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951726031
            Blower Motor Fan Resistors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951727031
            Blower Motors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951728031
            Condenser Fans: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/5121980031
            Condensers & Secondary Radiators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951729031
            Heat Exchangers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951730031
            Heater Control Valves: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951731031
            Heater Hoses: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951732031
            Heater Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951733031
            Receiver Dryers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4951735031
    Starters: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2503992031
    Steering & Suspension: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81353031
    Switches & Relays: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81498031
        Relays: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81499031
        Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/81501031
            Brake Light Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964571031
            Push Button Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964581031
            Blower: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964570031
            Interior Light: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964579031
            Toggle: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964587031
            Clutch: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964573031
            Air Pressure: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964569031
            Reverse Light Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964583031
            Circuit Breaker: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964572031
            Door Jamb: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964574031
            Ignition Starter: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964578031
    Windscreen Wipers & Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/83086031
        Replacement Blades: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/83089031
        Washer Pumps: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4964590031
        Windscreen Wipers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/83088031
        Wiper Motors: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/83087031
```

**Note**

The above links do not contain a suffix such as `/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_1_auto/262-0351978-4670353`, which appears to be some sort of "referer" parameter, but work well just the same. If you want the full links, then include a `User-Agent` header (it doesn't matter for this website too much what it is), for example:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'my-app/0.0.1' # add this line
```

Then the output will be as follows. But in the end I think the referer parameter is rather meaningless given how the pages are being fetched:

```
Car Parts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/79919031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_1_auto/260-7159013-6357941
    Alternators: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504415031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_2_79919031
    Batteries & Accessories: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82523031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_2_79919031
        Battery Charging Units: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82526031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_82523031
        Battery Switches: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933113031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_82523031
        Battery Testers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82527031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_82523031
        Car Batteries: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82524031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_82523031
        Jump Leads: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/82525031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_82523031
    Belts & Tensioners: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/2504430031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_2_79919031
        Idler Pulleys: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/8490903031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_2504430031
        Serpentine Belts: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/14343385031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_2504430031
        Tensioner Levers: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933115031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_2504430031
        Tensioner Pulleys: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/4933116031/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_3_2504430031
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways you can achieve the same.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'
unique_links = set()

def get_links(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    link_list = []
    for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
        item_link = item.get("href")
        if item_link not in unique_links:
            link_list.append(item_link)
            yield from print_links(item_link)
        unique_links.add(item_link)
        
    for new_link in link_list:
        yield from get_links(s,new_link)

def print_links(link):
    yield link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_links(s,link):
            print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you inspect automotive in browser, you will see that sublinks are not loaded until you open link in landing page in this case when you open car park then sub links of car park are loaded.

You are making only one request so it will only load links of landing page. You will have to loop the requests through links of landing page to get all sublinks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/automotive/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'

def fetch_all_links(link):
    landing_page_links = []
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
    if not soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):return
    for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
        landing_page_links.append(item.get("href"))
    yield landing_page_links
def fetch_sub_links():
    links = fetch_all_links()
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
        for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
            yield item.get("href")    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
        for elem in fetch_sub_links():
            print(elem)
```

Note that this might not get you all sub links only first two levels but i hope you get the idea about how it should be